# Getting error on AuthenticationParameters and AcquireToken

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am getting following errors:

**Code:**
string redirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUrl"];
AuthenticationParameters ap = **AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync**(new Uri(redirectUrl)).Result;

**Error:**
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(Uri)'    Pending email for Authorizers   C:\Users\handemv\source\Workspaces\Dynamics 365\Trunk-UCI\Tools\Automation_CapGSupport\Pending Email\Pending email for Authorizers\PendingEmailCheck.cs

**Code:**
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_authority, false);
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.**AcquireToken**(_serviceUri, clientCred);

**Error:**
AuthenticationContext' does not contain a definition for 'AcquireToken' and no accessible extension method 'AcquireToken' accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticationContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone help me for same?

Answer (score 0):

**`Error :`**  `AuthenticationContext' does not contain a definition for 'AcquireToken' and no accessible extension method 'AcquireToken' accepting a first argument of type 'AuthenticationContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

**Solution 1:**

This error due to **AcquireToken** was removed in v3 of the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` library.
To fix this downgrade the version in nuget to 2.22.302.111727    to solve  this error.

**Solution 2:**

In **V3 of ADAL.NET** which appears to no longer have `AcquireToken()`.
But it still has `AcquireTokenAsync()`. Note however that the parameters have slightly changed in the methods for v2 and v3.

For more details refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44599967/authenticationcontext-does-not-contain-the-definition-acquiretoken/44600250)

**`Error`**: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'AuthenticationParameters.CreateFromResourceUrlAsync(Uri)' Pending email for Authorizers`

Follow this link :https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/1410